# Create jQuery Dropdown Function for Login Form

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dropdown

I've been trying to replace an outdated plugin on my subscription-based WordPress site which has been giving me, up until now, the ability to embed my login form on the homepage with the ability for the form to be inside a dropdown that can be toggled to be open and closed (and it initially shows up closed when the site is first loaded).

What I want is this: A phrase ("Login & Account Details") that, when clicked, displays a dropdown containing the login form; and when clicked again collapses/closes the dropdown again.

I found the following in a WordPress forum (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-custom-login-form-to-navigation?replies=3#post-8649379), and adjusted it to fit my needs.

I added in the functions.php file of my child-theme:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#form-toggle').click(function() {
        jQuery('#login-form').toggle();
    });
});
```

I added into the homepage:

```
<div id="form-toggle">Login & Account Details</div>
<div id="login-form">
[login_form]
</div>
```

I added into the custom css:

```
#login-form {
display: none;
}

#form-toggle {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

However when I implemented it, it displayed the "Login & Account Details" *and* the login form was also visible by default. When the "Login & Account Details" is clicked, the dropdown collapses/closes, and when clicked again, drops down.

Is there any way to use the above code, but adjust it so that the dropdown does not appear expanded by default, but instead only appears after one clicks the "Login & Account Details" text?

Or is there another way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do? I'm very, very new to jQuery. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well, when I implemented this in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xp6bhgc/) it works correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#form-toggle').click(function() {
        jQuery('#login-form').toggle();
    });
});
```

With

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('#login-form').hide();
       jQuery('#form-toggle').click(function() {
            jQuery('#login-form').toggle();
       });
    });
```

Comment: @Mickey Thank you! Works perfectly!! FYI, to be able to use it in my child theme functions.php file in WordPress I had to adjust the above to this: 
`add_action('wp_footer', 'login_toggle');
function login_toggle() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('#login-form').hide();
       jQuery('#form-toggle').click(function() {
            jQuery('#login-form').toggle();
 });
</script>
<?php }` And I also didn't need the Custom CSS anymore!

Comment: Hi @Jutta, It is better to use wp_enque_script() function to include Javascripts instead of wp_footer

Comment: Hi @Mickey - thank you for that tip. I think I like using the wp_footer because it helps reduce load speed. How does the script load when using the wp_enque_script() function?

Comment: It will be included in the header and will go through all wp process. For example - if you use minify js to your site then that plugin or code will try to minify all scripts registered through wp_enque_script(). Actually by that way you are telling wp to include a script. But with wp_footer it is like adding a content to footer.

Comment: @Mickey: Something like this? `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'login_toggle' );
function login_toggle(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'login_toggle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/login_toggle.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
}` - I put this in the functions.php and made a .js file and placed it in my child theme. But the function isn't working. Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you are going in right direction, check your front end source code and search for 'login_toggle.js'. check whether it is there or not. If it is there check the link/src there. You may get the clue ;)

Comment: My concern is , get_template_directory_uri() might be giving you parent theme location, so as you have coded js inclusion may be done in the site but check src part of it. My be it is a invalid one.

Comment: Thanks. Source code shows /wp-content/themes/wp-zefir-child/login_toggle.js (I ended up using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead). However the function still doesn't work. Could I be doing something wrong in the .js file? This is my code: `jQuery(function() {
jQuery('#login-form').css('display', 'block');
       jQuery('#form-toggle').click(function() {
            jQuery('#login-dropdown').toggle();
       });
    });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118465/discussion-between-jutta-duncan-and-mickey).